# invoke a method in a servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, methods, invoke

I have this servlet   -

```
@WebServlet("/CreateNewPersonServlet")
public class CreateNewPersonServlet extends HttpServlet {
      private void saveInDB() {

            // here use the invoke ...
            String methodName = "saveManager";
            Method method = CreateNewPersonServlet.class.getMethod(
                    methodName, new Class[] {});
            method.invoke(this);

      }
      private void saveManager() {

      }

}
```

When the running reach to the line -

```
Method method = CreateNewPersonServlet.class.getMethod(
                        methodName, new Class[] {});
```

it throws the exception -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: control.CreateNewPersonServlet.saveManager()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
```

How I should write the invoke correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is private, you should use `.getDeclaredMethod(..)`, and then use `setAccessible(true)`

`.getMethod(..)` returns only public methods. But you may as well make the method public.